MariaDB: Strange behavior of GRANT statement
I have MariaDB 10.6 with two local users TOM and JOHN.
I signed into the database with ROOT and create a database with a table:
create database db1;
create table db1.tab1(txt text);
insert into db1.tab1('first row');

then I granted insert and Select privileges to TOM:
grant select on db1.tab1 to 'tom'@'localhost';
query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)
grant insert on db1.tab1 to 'tom'@'localhost' with grant option;
query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

Then I signed into the db with TOM. Both privileges worked and I could select and Insert on db1.tab1;
Then I tried to grant select on the table to user JOHN (with TOM) and unbelievably it worked and I didn't get any error:
grant select on db1.tab1 to 'john'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

And when I switched to JOHN the grant worked successfully!
then I tried to grant insert on the table to user JOHN (with TOM) and it worked too:
grant insert on db1.tab1 to 'john'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

I'm really confused why the select grant worked as well and I didn't get any error.
Update1:
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------             -----------------------------+
| Grants for tom@localhost                                                                                                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------             -----------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `tom`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A4B6157319038             724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `db1`.`tab1` TO `tom`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------             -----------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)


MariaDB [(none)]> show grants for 'john'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for john@localhost                                                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `john`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*A4B6157319038724E3560894F7F932C8886EBFCF' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON `db1`.`tab1` TO `john`@`localhost`                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

As you can see, TOM has GRANT OPTION on both SELECT and INSERT without me giving it to him.

Please post the output of show grants for  'tom'@'localhost' and  show grants for  'john'@'localhost'. It seems that tom use has the permission to grant and john user doesn't

I posted the output and edited my mistake. please read the last line again. Thanks.

You have posted the command used for the access, I have request the grants for both users . Run the commands I have mentioned and then post the result

I posted the update. Thanks

WITH GRANT OPTION is an option which is applied to the whole permissions pack. Execute SHOW GRANTS for root user - you'll see 3 separate permissions blocks. When you grant WITH GRANT OPTION to any permision within the pack then you grant this option to the whole pack.

I think you are right. WITH GRANT OPTION works for the whole Priv_level and not for a specific privilege. Thanks
